# Could Not Resolve Dependencies for AndroidSweetSheet library

Tags: java, android, android-studio, github

So I am back working on my Android app after a few months and after having familiarized myself with the code again, I notice that my `AndroidSweetSheet` library has become somewhat deprecated since the compiler is failing to resolve the dependency. This is strange considering the fact that all used to work and was honkey dorey.

What could be the issue because when I navigate to:

https://repo.jfrog.org/artifactory/libs-release-bintray/com/github/zzz40500/AndroidSweetSheet/221317862b/AndroidSweetSheet-221317862b.jar?referrer

I get an http 404 stating that the resource I have just requested could not be found:

```
{
  "errors" : [ {
    "status" : 404,
    "message" : "Could not find resource"
  } ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I needed to do was:

**1.** Update my `Android Support Repository`

**2.** Update my `buildToolsVersion` from `'23.0.0'` to `'25.0.0'` (the latest). I left my `compileSdkVersion` at `23`. Synced Gradle files and that resolved the issue.